# Dell optiplex 960 reboots but should sleep

Tags: windows-vista, dell-optiplex, hybrid-sleep

I have Dell Optiplex 960 with Vista Business 64-bit.

Everyday after work I'm clicking "shut down" button which puts my machine into hybrid-sleep mode.
It works great, but once a week just before saving whole memory to the disk, the computer restarts and I see a screen with options how to run my windows because of it.

I have similiar machine at home - DIY with Gigabyte motherboard, Vista Home Premium 64-bit - and had never saw such behaviour.

I found somwhere on the internet that disabling "Allow this device to wake up computer" checkbox for keyboard and mouse may help, but not in my case :-(

There is almost no information about those crashes in Event Viewer. For example yesterday I can find in System Log error at 18:03 that last shutdown from 18:01 was unexpected, but I have a hole in logs beetwen 14:58 and 18:02.

Should I search for some newer drivers or bios updates ?

**EDIT:** I've updated BIOS from version A01 to A03. Next day it happend again :-(
Anyone know how to track drivers responsible for such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 weeks ago I upgraded my Vista to SP2 and from now on the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the BIOS updates, then go to drivers.  I just updated my BIOS and it fixed a long-standing issue with my USB ports.

JFV